# How was it decided that Predicate "and" method would have a consumer and not producer in java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, pecs

I was going through the Predicate class introduced in java 8 which is functional interface.
There is a method and inside the Predicate class which is as following for composing multiple predicates into one.

```
default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
}
```

I have read the concept of PECS in java but still couldn't understand why in the case of Predicate we are using `? super T`. How have the java programmers decided that it would be a consumer and not a producer.

I mean why lines with compile errors should not be allowed:

```
public class PredicateExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Number> pred = n -> n.intValue() > 2;
        Predicate<Integer> predInt = n -> n > 3;
        //Compile error
        //pred.and(predInt);

        Predicate<Object> predObj = o -> Integer.parseInt(o.toString()) > 4;
        pred.and(predObj); //Valid statement

        Number n = new Integer(100);
        System.out.println(pred.and(predObj).test(10));
        System.out.println(predInt.and(pred).test(10));
        //Compile error
        //System.out.println(pred.and(predInt).test(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal is to create a `Predicate` that can decide something for objects of type `T`. A predicate that deals with super classes of `T` can decide things for `T` as well. For example, suppose you create a predicate for dogs, `Predicate<Dog>` and then you want to combine it with a predicate that deals with `Animal`s, `Predicate<Animal>`, for example a predicate that can decide whether the animal is over 10 years old. Such a predicate can be used for dogs as well. So it would be unecessary to limit yourself only to predicates for dogs, when general animal-predicates work as well.

Comment: @Zabuzard the comment is equivalent to my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Predicate<T>`s take in a `T` and give you a `boolean`. Yes, it is a producer of `boolean`s, but that's not really relevant here. *When applying PECS on a type parameter, you should think about whether the type is a producer or consumer **of that type parameter***.

Since `Predicate<T>` accepts a `T`, it's a consumer of `T`, so it should be `? super` for the `T` parameter.

Another example: `BiFunction<T, U, V>` accepts a `T` and a `U`, and produces a `V`, so it's a consumer of `T`, consumer of `U`, and producer of `V`. Therefore, `? super` for `T` and `U`, `? extends` for `V`. As you can see, only the type parameters matter. Anything else that the type might do, doesn't.

The lines will be allowed if you flip the two sides - `predInt.and(pred)`, which creates a `Predicate<Integer>`.

This is because `and` is declared to produce the same type of predicate as the one it is called on, so `pred.and(...)` can only produce a `Predicate<Number>`, but a `Predicate<Number>` doesn't make sense here - the other conjunct can only accept integers!

You can totally make it work in both orders. If you declare `and` as a static method:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> a, Predicate<? super T> b)
```

Then you can do both of these:

```
and(predInt, pred)
and(pred, predInt)
```

But it's less readable this way :(

Answer (score 4):

**Producer** - Gives an object to you by returning it: [`T get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--)
The object must be a `T` or a subclass thereof, so it `extends`.

**Consumer** - Takes an object from you as method parameter: [`void accept(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-)
The method may take a more general type, but cannot require a more specific type, so parameter can be a `super`.

Since the Predicate [`boolean test(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-) method takes the object as argument, it's a consumer.

<sup>*Reference: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/5221149)*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The problem with

```
    Predicate<Number> pred = n -> n.intValue() > 2;
    Predicate<Integer> predInt = n -> n > 3;
    //Compile error
    //pred.and(predInt);
```

is that the `pred` accepts all subclasses of `Number` (for example also `Double`) but `predInt` accepts only one specific subclass (`Integer`).

The following code is therefore fine:

```
    Number n = Double.valueOf(100);
    System.out.println(pred.test(n));
```

But the following code (if it would compile) would fail at runtime:

```
    Number n = Double.valueOf(100);
    System.out.println(pred.and(predInt).test(n));
```

Since generics were introduced exactly to prevent such runtime failures it must prevent the code from compiling (i.e. produce a compile error).

Comment: If I get it right, OP is aware of all that and was specifically asking for the terminology of PECS (see the details in his question and the comment section).